# How do I reference a variable used in an unsafe block?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to read 4 bytes from a socket and then transmute those bytes into a single u32.

```
let mut length: u32 = 0;

// Transmute 4 byte array into u32
unsafe {
    let length = mem::transmute::<[u8; 4], u32>(buf); // buf is the 4 item array of u8 that the socket was read into
    println!("1: {:}", length);
}

println!("Length: {:}", length);
```

However, length has the original value of 0 once outside of the unsafe block. How can I get around this?

Comment: I believe you're shadowing the outer binding with an inner binding. Try assigning it without `let` the second time.

Comment: yup, @TheodorosChatzigiannakis is right, you can remove the "let" inside the unsafe (let introduces a new binding, but here you want to reuse a previous one): [example](http://is.gd/Gv9U0A)

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis What do you know? That works. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the inner block, you're not assigning a new value to the outer `length` binding, [you are *shadowing* it](http://rustbyexample.com/variable_bindings/scope.html) by defining a new `length` binding.

I believe that in a simple code snippet such as this (where the outer mutable variable isn't reassigned) normally there should be a compiler warning along the lines of:

> warning: variable does not need to be mutable

In any case, since you have declared an outer mutable binding, all you have to do to re-assign the original variable is drop the keyword `let` in the `unsafe` block.

Additionally, as pointed out in the comments:

- There's no need to initialize this particular binding with a value, because that value is always going to be replaced before it is ever used.
- If you aren't really re-assigning that variable later on (in code not shown in your question), then it doesn't even need to be mutable. Mutability doesn't force you to initialize the variable at the point of its declaration in the source code.

So this should suffice:

```
let length: u32; // or mut  
unsafe {
    length = mem::transmute::<[u8; 4], u32>(buf);
    println!("1: {:}", length);
}

println!("Length: {:}", length);
```

Answer (score 6):

Note (in addition to Theodoros' answer) that unsafe block is an expression, so you can do this:

```
let buf = [1u8, 2, 3, 4];

// Transmute 4 byte array into u32
let length = unsafe {
    let length = std::mem::transmute::<[u8; 4], u32>(buf); // buf is the 4 item array of u8 that the socket was read into
    println!("1: {:}", length);
    length
};

println!("Length: {:}", length);
```

Or in short:

```
let length = unsafe {std::mem::transmute::<[u8; 4], u32>(buf)};
```